# CSS navigation?

Tags: css

The navigation on the left menu in the below site uses CSS for mouseover links.
[PVH](http://www.pvh.com/)

When I take the code of the navigation and make it separate page. Then the mouseover links are not working. What could be the reason?
[Test](http://shivanand.in/tmp/navigation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably...

```
<script src="menu_1b.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="menu_com.js" type="text/javascript">
```

have something to say on the matter. EDIT: A function called function CreateMenuStructureAgain() kind of gives it away.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "borrow" the scripts found at

```
http://www.pvh.com/menu_1b.js
http://www.pvh.com/menu_com.js
```

and then link to them using

```
<script src="menu_1b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="menu_com.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You could probably try

```
<script src="http://www.pvh.com/menu_1b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.pvh.com/menu_com.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it will work (provided that you have an internet connection, and they don't modify the scripts :D)

Comment: I have added the Js files. In IE it is not working. In firefox it works but improperly. Please check below screenshot
"http://shivanand.in/tmp/mouseover-links.gif"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you needed to take the scripts too.  I was going to take a look at a solution for you but then I opened the JS code you were attempting to use.  You could do a lot better with a lot less code.  Try looking at [this menu example](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/vertical.html) and the [accompanying code](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/).  You should be able to do exactly what you need without the need for vast amounts of Javascript.